# Wordpress permalink Apache mod_rewrite enable but still not working

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have a server with Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.3.27 and Wordpress installed.

When I try to use permalinks on Wordpress, I get 404 error.

The rewrite module is enabled:

```
$ httpd -M 

Output

rewrite_module (shared)
```

Here is my httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
<Directory>
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything seems to be fine, but I still get 404 error when I change Permalinks to **Post Name** in Wordpress admin.

I hope to get help.

Comment: Wordpress version 5.7

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on this and can't figure out. I made backup reload and just w